# Displaying Area under Precision-Recall Curve in new Sklearn version (1.0.2)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision-recall

The new Sklearn version has removed the attribute `from_predictions` from [PrecisionRecallDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_predictions). In the example provided in the docs, a curve is generated, but without the area under the curve displayed.

[image]

How would one display the AUC for this curve on the chart?

Comment: I checked with the sklearn 1.0.2 version, it is working fine - able to add the area in the label. Kindly check your code.

Comment: Before it was adding the area by default- is it doing that or are you writing some code to add it in ? If so what code?

Comment: no, by default it does it.